# Multiple Keyword Search in Magento2

Tags: magento2, search, advanced-search

Magento / Magento 2 by default has Keyword based search - which bring in search results from all the attributes marked as searchable, and Advance Search, where in we can search in multiple attributes using exact values.

I need a help to create a different module in Magento 2. I want to search multiple keywords in single attribute.

For Eg : I enter comma separated values in Search Box, which brings back search results searching the values from Product Name. Eg : rice, wheat, bread, milk and i get the results of above all 4 keywords matching it with product name or any particular searchable keyword.

I was able to do the same using calling the product collection and customizing a new module. But doing in this manner, while we enable Elastic Search or Solr on the store the results still come from Mysql. Hence i want to call the actual Search Model so that i get the results from Elastic Search or Solr.

Any idea on how to create this module ?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/mageworx-module-searchsuiteautocompletemeta.html https://marketplace.magento.com/instantsearch-instantsearchplus.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the module Ankit. I already have autocomplete and other features included. What i need is : searching on multiple keywords in single search box. Eg : rice, milk, wheat, bread : And the search list page gives me results for above all keywords.